# Hashed and Salt with CAPICOM ? SHA 512 using asp-classic

Tags: asp-classic, hash, salt, sha512

I would like to know if this method is safe to use for login since this is the only one I found that is easy to understand and that it is in asp-classic so that I a noob can understand and add to the site I have.

Thanks

```
    <%
    Dim sDigest,sPassword,sSalt
    sDigest=SHA256(sRndStr)


    sPassword = Request.Form("pass")
    sSalt = Request.Form("username") & "SomeThingThatisStatic1234567890"

    With CreateObject("CAPICOM.HashedData") 
      .Algorithm = 6 '<--- This will use SHA-512
      'CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA1      = 0 
      'CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_MD2       = 1 
      'CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_MD4       = 2 
      'CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_MD5       = 3 
      'CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA_256   = 4 - Not supported on Windows XP or 2000 
      'CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA_384   = 5 - Not supported on Windows XP or 2000 
      'CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA_512   = 6 - Not supported on Windows XP or 2000 

      .Hash sPassword & sSalt 

'Response.Write "Here is your hash: " & .Value 
'---> here i would then check this hash with the hash in the database
'---> and if it's the same let the user login if not go to error: wrong info.
    End With 
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I've missed something fairly crucial, it doesn't look particularly safe. In particular, it looks like you're sending the hash of the salt/password over the connection, and verifying that on the server. If so, it's open to a replay attack -- i.e., somebody taps into the conversation, sees what the user responded with to log in, and then logs in under those credentials by sending the same responses. Hashing/salting the password prevents them from knowing the user's original password, but they don't care -- the know the hash, and that's all the server checks to let them log on.

To avoid that, you usually want to use a challenge/response setup:

1. The user sends something to say they want to log in
2. The server generates a random number and sends it to the user
3. The client encrypts the random number using their hashed/salted password as the key, and sends the result back to the server along with their user name
4. The server does the same encryption with its idea of that user's hashed/salted password
5. The server compares the two encrypted numbers

Each time a user tries to log in, the server generates a new/different random number. Even if somebody has the packets from an earlier login, they won't let the spy log in again.

Comment: but if the random number keeps changing how will the encriptyion/hash value be the same ? doesn't it have to be the same ?

Comment: because I thought that if the user will enter their username and password and send this to the server, the server will then hash and salt all of their info that they send to it and then check with the database (that is on the same server) to see if the hash matches

Comment: @user1612407: In that case it's even worse than I guessed -- you're sending the user's credentials in the clear over the network, basically giving their credentials to anybody spying on them/the server. Storing the hashed PW in a database is fine though -- that just affects where the server gets "its idea of the user's hashed/salted password" in step 4. But no, you do not want what goes over the wire to remain constant -- if it does, it's open to a replay attack.

Comment: @user1612407: Revealing the user's password to others is a bad thing, so if you ever send it over the wire, you need to encrypt it first. Replay attacks aren't quite a bad, but still dangerous, so you want to ensure that every login requires a unique/different set of responses from any other.

Comment: Okay, sorry I took like one hour to respond I was reading abit more about this so I can get a better understanding of this and I understand now that it is not safe at all to send the username and password in cleartext because someone can be snooping, so the best way would be to make a random salt, but if the salt is random and keeps changing then how will they pair up to authenticate the user? it would always be different ???

Comment: @user1612407: No, the salt doesn't change. The *challenge* changes every time the user wants to log in.

Comment: so something like this: the server sends the user a challenge like a random number that random number is used to generate a hash by using the users password on the client side and then sends it back to the server along with the username, the server then does the same and if the results are the same it lets them in. So when the user visits the login I should get their ip address and generate a random number and store the two in a database and then send the client the same number for their challenge? this way the server will know what the random number was and for who it is, right?